# does python's urllib2 do connection pooling?

Tags: java, python, urllib2

Really what I'm wondering: is python's urllib2 more like java's `HttpUrlConnection`, or more like apache's `HttpClient`? And, ultimately I'm wondering if urllib2 scales when used in a http server, or if there is some alternate library that is used when performance is an issue (as is the case in the java world).

To expand on my question a bit:

Java's HttpUrlConnection internally holds one connection open per host, and does pipelining. So if you do the following concurrently across threads it won't perform well:

```
HttpUrlConnection cxn = new Url('www.google.com').openConnection();
InputStream is = cxn.getInputStream();
```

By comparison, apache's HttpClient can be initialized with a connection pool, like this:

```
    // this instance can be a singleton and shared across threads safely:
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cm = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
    HttpConnectionManagerParams p = new HttpConnectionManagerParams();
    p.setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostConfiguration.ANY_HOST_CONFIGURATION,20);
    p.setMaxTotalConnections(100);
    p.setConnectionTimeout(100);
    p.setSoTimeout(250);
    cm.setParams(p);

    client.setHttpConnectionManager(cm);
```

The important part in the example above being that the number of total connections and the per-host connections are configurable.

In a comment urllib3 was mentioned, but I can't tell from reading the docs if it allows a per-host max to be set.

Comment: I'm not sure about the two you mentioned, but check out urllib3 for connection pooling: http://code.google.com/p/urllib3/

Answer (score 0):

As of Python 2.7.14rc1, No.

For `urllib`, `urlopen()` [eventually calls `httplib.HTTP`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c707893f9cee870bba8364b3a06eb9cfa3b80e58/Lib/urllib.py#L339), which [creates a new instance](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c707893f9cee870bba8364b3a06eb9cfa3b80e58/Lib/httplib.py#L1158) of `HTTPConnection`. `HTTPConnection` is tied to a socket and has methods for opening and closing it.

For `urllib2`, `HTTPHandler` [does something similar](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c707893f9cee870bba8364b3a06eb9cfa3b80e58/Lib/urllib2.py#L1228) and creates a new instance of `HTTPConnection`.